# Understanding Array.fill method signature in Scala

Tags: scala

I have some trouble understanding the following method signature in [Array.scala](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.8/src/library/scala/Array.scala#L280):

```
def fill[T: ClassTag](n1: Int, n2: Int)(elem: => T): Array[Array[T]]
```

I have read up on the concept of a polymorphic method from here:
http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/121.html

The method `fill` does appear to be parameterized by type `T` with value parameters. The method signature here confuses me though. It appears to be a "curried function" that takes multiple parameters but then there are two parameters `n1`, and `n2` in one parentheses and a function is passed in as a second parameter. That is like a higher-order function being passed into `fill`. But that does not look quite right either.

If anyone can point me in the right direction with a clue I can figure out more about how the `fill` method works, like the method body.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method you've quoted here creates, and fills, a 2-dimensional array.  The first 2 parameters, the `Int`s, dictate the dimensions (X & Y axis) of the array.

The 3rd parameter is in a separate parameter group. That's the curried part.  If it had been written `fill(n1, n2, elem)` then it would not be a curried method.  Or all the parameters could have been curried: `fill(n1)(n2)(elem)`.  In Haskell all parameters are curried.

The `elem: => T` notation means that this is a "by name" parameter.  It looks similar to a function definition but that's not the case.  It simply means that the received parameter, `elem`, is not evaluated at call time.  It is evaluated when referenced, which might be never.  For example:

```
Array.fill(x,y)(/*some-long-calculation*/)
```

In this case if either `x` or `y` are zero then the "long-calculation" is not executed.

Comment: So this is like partial currying?  I was under the impression that all parameters in Scala are either curried or not.

Comment: You could call it "partial currying" but I think the more common terminology would say that `fill()` is curried but not all of its parameters are curried. You can read a little more about Scala currying [here](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/control-abstraction.html#9.3).

Comment: I like the answer. Thank you.